# Python Splitting Text file based on a keyword

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python program that will constantly read a text file line by line and each time it comes across a line with the word 'SPLIT' it will write the contents to a new text file.

Please could someone point me in the right direction of writing a new text file each time the script comes across the word 'split'. I have no problem reading a text file with Python, I'm unsure how to split on the keyword and create an individual text file each time.

THE SCRIPT BELOW WORKS IN 2.7.13

```
file_counter = 0
done = False

with open('test.txt') as input_file:
   # with open("test"+str(file_counter)+".txt", "w") as out_file:
    while not done:
        for line in input_file:
            if "SPLIT" in line:
                done = True
                file_counter += 1
            else:
                print(line)
                out_file = open("test"+str(file_counter)+".txt", "a")
                out_file.write(line)
                #out_file.write(line.strip()+"\n")
                print file_counter
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you post sample input and expected output?

Comment: Which piece do you need help with?  The splitting, the file i/o, the looping, something else?  Let's get specific, and let's see what code you have so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two loops. One which iterates the filenames of the output files then another inside to write the input contents to the current active output until "split" is found:

```
out_n = 0
done = False
with open("test.txt") as in_file:
    while not done: #loop over output file names
        with open(f"out{out_n}.txt", "w") as out_file: #generate an output file name
            while not done: #loop over lines in inuput file and write to output file
                try:
                    line = next(in_file).strip() #strip whitespace for consistency
                except StopIteration:
                    done = True
                    break
                if "SPLIT" in line: #more robust than 'if line == "SPLIT\n":'
                    break
                else:
                    out_file.write(line + '\n') #must add back in newline because we stripped it out earlier 
            out_n += 1 #increment output file name integer
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. I have tried using your script but I get an error on line 8 of your code in relation to 'TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator' at the start of the code I added input_file = 'test.txt' to declare my input file. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @user826436 my bad... typo fixed.. you need the file object as the iterator and I accidentally typed the variable for the file path

Comment: Aaron, I couldn't get your script to fully compile properly. I have adapted your code and now I have the problem of my  the script running through each line in my text file and writes it to a new file. When it comes across 'SPLIT' it just stops. I need it to create a new text file and carry on writing lines until it hits 'SPLIT' again. Thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: @user826436 (python doesn't "compile") are you using python 3.5+ or 2.7? I used a format string which is a new feature with python 3 and won't work in python 2. What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Well I was using the latest python but then I downgrade to 2.7. My current script shown above works to a certain degree but it only writes to the same file instead of a new file. The counter works as each time SPLIT is found then it get incremented to make sure that the new file has a different file name.

Comment: okay.. I actually put it into an IDE and tried it out myself.. see changes. (I was previously just trying to go from memory)

Comment: Okay, when I try to complie yours I receive an invalid syntax in relation to   f"out{out_n}.txt"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155972/discussion-between-aaron-and-user826436).

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in text.splitlines():
    if " SPLIT " in line:
        # write in new file. 
        pass
```

To write in new file check here:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm
or 
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open